# Autocomplete from php source file requerying source page rather than call PHP Source file

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use the JQuery Autocomplete with PHP source file, but when I check with FIREBUG I see on change of the Input field, the page is just requerying itself rather than call my source PHP file

Code Segment

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#item_name").autocomplete("./utilities.php?op=autocomplete", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: true,
        minChars: 2,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

PHP SOURCE FILE

```
if($op=='autocomplete'){
        $dataset = array();
        $item_name = $_REQUEST['item_name'];
        if (!$item_name) return;
        $sql = "select select concat(item_id,' - ',item_name) item from payment_items where item_name like '%$item_name%'";
            //echo $sql;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($result){
            for($i=0; $i<$numrows; $i++){
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row['item'];
            }
            }

    }
```

The utilities file is a UTILITY PAGE so the need to define an $op parameter to determine what I want to achieve.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try removing the '.'

```
$("#item_name").autocomplete("/utilities.php?op=autocomplete", {
```

then it should be requesting the PHP page instead of itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#item_name").autocomplete("/utilities.php?op=autocomplete", 
{
  width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: true,
    minChars: 2,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
// your built function call
  myDefinedFunction(data);

 // update with another result
 $(this).val('your value');
```

})

As in documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler